# How to add up many BigDecimals in Java

Tags: java, bigdecimal

I have this program in which I need to add up many BigDecimals. I have the following snippet of code

```
BigDecimal Average = new BigDecimal(3.0);
BigDecimal ATT = new BigDecimal(0.0);
ATT.add(A_BigDecimal);
ATT.add(B_BigDecimal);
ATT.add(C_FullBigDecimal);
System.out.println("Total Amount: " + ATT); 
System.out.println("Average: " + ATT.divide(Average));
```

I keep getting errors everytime I try variants of this code, how do you add many BigDecimals together?
Edit: Forgot to mention that the output is zero, always zero, as if the reference variable isnt reading the add function.

Comment: What errors do you get?

Comment: @Steve for some reason the output is zero, I am really stuck

Comment: You should provide a reproducible example. `A_BigDecimal`, `B_BigDecimal` and `C_FullBigDecimal` are used but not defined anywhere.

Comment: Did you *read* the javadoc of [`add(BigDecimal augend)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#add-java.math.BigDecimal-)? ***Returns** a BigDecimal whose value is (this + augend)* Or the javadoc of [`BigDecimal`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) itself? ***Immutable**, arbitrary-precision signed decimal numbers.*

Answer (score 3):

`BigDecimal` is immutable.  Once the object is created, it cannot be changed.

The `add` method will return the result of the calculation.  You will probably want to assign that return value to something.

Answer (score 1):

This is what Joe C meant in updated code:

```
BigDecimal Average = new BigDecimal(3.0);
BigDecimal ATT = new BigDecimal(0.0);
ATT = ATT.add(A_BigDecimal);
ATT = ATT.add(B_BigDecimal);
ATT = ATT.add(C_FullBigDecimal);
System.out.println("Total Amount: " + ATT); 
System.out.println("Average: " + ATT.divide(Average));
```